# How to hide an element after clicking it's child element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, hide, show-hide

I want to hide ul.media-boxes-drop-down-menu area after clicking any menu http://prntscr.com/7j5rmz item. I was tried many times with different different codes. But I was unable to solve it. Any one can help me how may I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see any code, please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: please provide some code otherwise we cant just figure out

Comment: You need to add some code

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous. from what i have understood.

```
<ul id="ul_1">
<li >Some text</li>
</ul>   


<ul class="active" id="ul_2">
<li >Some text</li>
</ul>
```

clicking on ul_1 will hide ul_2, refactor the code according to your need.

```
 $('#ul_1').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#ul_2').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
    });
```

Comment: Sorry this method will not work for me. Here is the link http://jesmincms.com/desarrollo/ for your check.

Comment: kindly share code if you need any further assistance.

Comment: I was used this code: 
$('.media-boxes-drop-down-menu ul li a').click(function(){
$(".media-boxes-drop-down-menu").hide();
});

but it's not working there.

Here is the link of project: http://jesmincms.com/desarrollo/

Answer (score 0):

you have to give a class to that element you want to hide and then on-click() event you have to search that element inside wrapper main div like:

$('.elementTohode',$(this).parent().parent()).css('display','none')